# How to automatically delete a voice channel without people

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

So I am using [`discord.py`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to make a discord [`Client`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#client). I am using [`on_voice_state_update`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_voice_state_update) to see if the [`VoiceState`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceState) of a member changes.

If there are no people in the [`VoiceChannel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#voicechannel) in a specific [`Category`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#categorychannel), I want the client to delete the channel automatically. Here is my code:

```py
import discord, asyncio

app = discord.Client()

@app.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member_id, before, after):
    name2 = str(member_id)
    ch = app.get_channel(660213767820410918)
    guild = app.get_guild(660213767820410893)
    author = member_id
    member = after.channel.members
    category=guild.get_channel(660213767820410908)
    if after.channel == ch:
        channel2 = await guild.create_voice_channel(name=(name2+'`s Room'), category=guild.get_channel(660213767820410908) ,user_limit=99)
        await author.move_to(channel2)
        await channel2.set_permissions(author, manage_channels=True)
    if before.channel.members == None:
        await delete(before.channel)
```

But it doesn't work. Could anybody please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few errors, some of them which I alreay explained in my answer to your last question. Here is a fix:

```py
import discord, asyncio

app = discord.Client()

@app.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):
    username = str(member)
    guild = app.get_guild(660213767820410893)
    ch = guild.get_channel(660213767820410918)
    category = guild.get_channel(660213767820410908)

    if after.channel == ch:
        channel = await guild.create_voice_channel(
            name=username+"`s Room",
            category=category,
            user_limit=99
        )
        await member.move_to(channel)
        await channel.set_permissions(member, manage_channels=True)
    if not before.channel.members and before.channel != ch:
        await before.channel.delete()
```

Comment: I love you,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

Comment: but How to set exception All channels are deleted